# Is there a closed form equation for fibonacci(n) modulo m?

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Basically I am curious if there's a direct way to calculate fibonacci(n) modulo m with a closed form formula so I don't have to bother with matrix exponentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet a complete solution; just a heuristical approach. I'm considering the cyclicity of residues modulo some *m*, here only for $m \in \mathbb P$ . After this we need only the sequences along one cycle.
I give a couple of empricial results, organized such that they shall give a hint how to proceed:

$$ \small \begin{array} {lll}
&m & \operatorname{fibcyclelength}(m)  & \text{ general rule,estimated }\\
\hline \\ 
\hline \\
p=2& 2,4,8,16,32,... &3,6,12,24,48,...& a=(2+1),a_k=a \cdot 2^{k-1} \\ 
p=5& 5,25,125,625,...&20,100,500,... & a=5(5-1),a_k=a \cdot 5^{k-1}\\ 
\hline \\ 
p=\pm 2 \pmod 5 & 3,9,27,81,...   &8,24,72,216,... &a=2(3+1),a_k=a \cdot 3^{k-1}   \\
& 13,169,...      &28,364,...&a=2(13+1),a_k=a \cdot 13^{k-1}   \\
& 23,23^2         &48,&a=2(23+1), a_k=a \cdot 23^{k-1}\\
\hline \\  
& 7,49,343        &16,112,...&a=2(7+1),a_k=a \cdot 7^{k-1}  \\
& 17,289          &36,612,...&a=2(17+1),a_k=a \cdot 17^{k-1}    \\
\hline \\
p= \pm 1 \pmod 5& 11,121,         &10,110,  &  a=(11-1),a_k=a \cdot 11^{k-1}  \\
& 31,             &30,...&a=(31-1), a_k=a \cdot 31^{k-1}  \\
\hline  \\ 
& 19,...          &18,...&a=(19-1), a_k=a \cdot 19^{k-1}  \\
\end{array}
$$
I'm pretty confident that this is generalizable in the obvious way. Thus -if that above scheme is correct- we can compute the required results for that *m* without matrix-exponentiation after we have the entries over *one* cycle only..

Next step is then to look at the squarefree n with two primefactors, and their powers. Their sequences seem to begin with some irregularity, but finally seem to become regular in the above way. I've looked at *n=6*, *n=10*, *n=15* so far, and if I get some idea of the characteristic of the irregularity I'll post it here.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is old news, but it is straightforward to say what I know about this, in terms which I think there is some chance of addressing the intent of the question.

That is, as hinted-at by the question, the recursion $\pmatrix{F_{n+1}\cr F_n}=\pmatrix{1 & 1 \cr 1 & 0}\cdot \pmatrix{F_n\cr F_{n-1}}$ can be usefully dissected by thinking about eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Namely, the minimal (also characteristic) equation is $(x-1)x-1=0$, which has roots more-or-less the golden ratio. Thus, doing easy computations which I'm too lazy/tired to do on this day at this time, $F_n=A\cdot a^n + B\cdot b^n$ for some constants $a,b,A,B$. These constants are algebraic numbers, lying in the field extension of $\mathbb Q$ obtained by adjoining the "golden ratio"... This expression might seem not to make sense mod $m$, but, perhaps excepting $m$ divisible by $2$ or $5$, the finite field $\mathbb Z/p$ allows sense to be made of algebraic extensions, even with denominators dividing $2$ or $5$, the salient trouble-makers here.

So, except possibly for $m$ divisible by $2$ or $5$, the characteristic-zero formula for the $n$-th Fibonacci number makes sense.

The further question, raised in the other answer, of the precise *period* mod $m$ is probably as intractable (currently) as questions about primitive roots... Indeed. But, perhaps, the given question is not that hard...?

Comment: Keep on truckin', bro...

Answer (score 1):

Mod 19 there are two solutions to $x^2=x+1$, the generating function for Fibonacci numbers. These are $x=5, x=15$. On a whim (based on some of the above comments), I thought I would try these to get a closed form for fibonacci numbers mod 19. I tried
$$f(n) = \frac{15^n-5^n}{15-5},$$
where the computation is to be done mod 19.
And the formula worked, at least as far as I tried it.

(I'm just including this answer because it surprised me; perhaps the other responders above already know such a thing has to work.)

ADDED: The above seems to work fine for any prime for which $x^2=x+1$ has two solutions. I got that this is primes for which 5 is a quadratic residue. (it didn't work for $p=5$ since the only solution there is $x=3$ and then cannot imitate the above formula.)

Also I found that it seems to work even for $209 = 11 \cdot 19$, where there are four solutions, namely $15,81,129,195$; however one needs to choose a pair so that their difference is coprime to 209. Thus for mod 209 I tried the formula
$$f(n)=\frac{129^n-81^n}{129-81}$$ and that seems to work to give fibonacci numbers mod 209.