# Is there a pattern of the factorization of a polynomial modulo $p$ as $p$ varies

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Take $P\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and factorize it modulo $p$, where $p$ is a prime.

Modulo different $p$'s the factorization varies. Is there a pattern in this variation? I mean,  for example, if $P$ is quartic, it can factorize as "linear*cubic", "quadratic*quadratic", "quadratic*linear*linear" and so on. Does it tend to factorize more in one way than in the other ways?

I came up with this question, because I am calculating these factorizations of a few polynomials, and they tend to "prefer" certain ways of factorization. This is looking curious, though of course, it could just be the odds.

Comment: Are you assuming $P \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ irreducible?  I think one might as well, since the factors $\mod p$ for sufficiently large primes will reflect factors of the irreducible factors over the integers.

Comment: Isn't this what the whole theory of arithmetic Zeta functions is all about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you are onto something. I like to use the variable $z$ for this. I forget what happens if you factor $z^3 - 2 \pmod 3.$ After that, there is one simple pattern when $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3,$ when you factor $z^3 - 2 \pmod p.$ That is, a linear factor times a quadratic.

Here is the cute bit: once $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3,$ and you factor $z^3 - 2 \pmod p,$ you get two wildly different outcomes: if there is an expression $p = x^2 + 27 y^2$ in integers, you get three linear terms, distinct. However, if  $p = 4  x^2 + 2 x y + 7 y^2,$ irreducible.

Go Figure.

A similar example, see [Numbers represented by a cubic form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336191/numbers-represented-by-a-cubic-form) 
and factor 
$$ z^3 - z^2 - z - 1  $$ separately for primes with Legendre $(p|11) = -1$ and then for $p = x^2 + 11 y^2$ and then for $p = 3 x^2 + 2 x y + 4 y^2.$ As before, when there is an $xy$ term, you need to allow $xy$ both positive and negative to get all possible such primes. For example, with $x=1,y=-1,3 x^2 + 2 x y + 4 y^2 =5. $

Quartic examples: factor $z^4 + 3 \pmod p,$ when (A) $p=2,3$, (B) larger $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ (C) $p = 5 x^2 \pm 4 xy + 8 y^2,$ (D) $p = 4 x^2 + 9 y^2,$ (E) $p = x^2 + 36 y^2$

Factor $z^4 + 2 z^2 - 7 \pmod p,$ when (A) $(-56|p) = -1,$  (B) $p = 3 x^2 \pm 2 xy + 5 y^2,$ (C) $p = 2 x^2 + 7 y^2,$ (D) $p = x^2 + 14 y^2.$ This is the one that is worked out in full in David A. Cox, *Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2.$* On page 188 of that book, Theorem 9.12 gives the  frequencies of the types of primes I have been specifying. This is an application of the Chebotarev Density that Qiaochu mentions.

I LIKE EXAMPLES. SUE ME.

=============================

[image]

=================================

Answer (score 8):

Good question! This is in fact a fairly deep question in number theory. Statistical patterns are given by [Chebotarev's density theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem), which predicts for example that for an irreducible quadratic polynomial you get two linear factors about half the time and a quadratic factor about half the time. In general, Chebotarev tells you that the frequency of each kind of factorization is controlled by the [Galois group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_group) of the polynomial.

Describing the exact primes at which various factorizations occur is hard. If $P$ has abelian Galois group, then the answer is given by [class field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_field_theory) and can be given in terms of congruence conditions on the primes. This is easiest to see for the [cyclotomic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). Already the application to quadratic polynomials is essentially [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity), which is nontrivial.

If $P$ is nonabelian, then the answer is more complicated. Even for simple nonabelian cases the exact description can involve more sophisticated mathematics like [modular forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form); for example, $P(x) = x^3 - x - 1$ is controlled by the modular form

$$q \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - q^n)(1 - q^{23n})$$

as described [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11747/galoisian-sets-of-prime-numbers). In some sense answering this question is the goal of (part of?) the [Langlands program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langlands_program).

Answer (score 2):

The factorization of an integral polynomial $f(x)$ modulo a prime $p$ is closely related to the decomposition of the prime $p$ in the splitting field of $f(x)$. For quadratic polynomials, the factoring is determined by the congruence class of $p$ modulo the discriminant of $f(x)$. In general, there are more things to consider. However, the answers lie in algebraic number theory.