# Can you put a ring structure on the group of units modulo $n$? What *other* rings are there?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $n=4$ Then with multiplication defined as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 3\\ 
1 & 3 & 0\\ 
3 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
i.e. $a_{i,j} = i \oplus j$.  Then combined with the group of units modulo $4$ multiplication law, we have a ring.   Questions:

1. Can you always put a ring structure on the group of units modulo $n$.
2. Has anyone studied uses for these in algebraic number theory?
3. Will we almost always require a ring or could we make use of something less like a ring that has a commutative semigroup instead of group.

Sorry for the broadness.

Comment: It's actually a field.  Does that mean it's isomorphic to a known field?

Comment: Finite fields are isomorphic up to cardinality, in this case $\mathbb{F}_3$.

Comment: Any finite abelian group is isomorphic to a direct product of copies of cyclic groups, so can be given a ring structure by considering the corresponding direct product of cyclic rings.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336191/numbers-represented-by-a-cubic-form for example. The construction I give is a ring, and the determinant is the norm form of a field. See answer by Noam Elkies at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/127160/numbers-integrally-represented-by-a-ternary-cubic-form